# ftp_put() function will not upload my file

Tags: php, ftp

I have searched for this error on google already and found a lot of posts from this website but nothing seems to work.
here is my from:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

and here is my php code from upload_file.php

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "xxx";
$ftp_username   = "xxx";
$ftp_password   =  "xxx";
$uploadedfile = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"];
//setup of connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");
//login
if(@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "conectd as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
}
else
{
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
$remote_file_path = "   /home/a9408563/public_html/files".$uploadedfile;
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $uploadedfile,FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($conn_id);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";
?>
```

and this is the error i am getting:
Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Can't open that file: No such file or directory in /home/a9408563/public_html/upload_file.php on line 18

i have no idea what to do next and any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer from the comments of php.net on ftp_put:

---

Found the prob, you can't put a path to the destination file
(even though I can do that in the dos ftp client...?)

e.g. - this doesn't work

```
ftp_put($conn, '/www/site/file.html','c:/wamp/www/site/file.html',FTP_BINARY);
```

you have to put

```
ftp_chdir($conn, '/www/site/');
ftp_put($conn,'file.html', 'c:/wamp/www/site/file.html', FTP_BINARY );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Comment: so i changed it to this:
ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/home/a9408563/public_html/files/');
ftp_put($conn_id, $uploadedfile, "  /home/a9408563/public_html/files".$uploadedfile, FTP_BINARY );

but it is still not working

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect("xxx"); 
$ftp_user_name="xxx";
$ftp_user_pass="xxx";
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
$destination_file =  $destination_file = "public_html/api/".$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$source_file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']; 
// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}
// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id); 
    }
?>
<html><body><form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form></body></html>


api is my target folder
```